# ASP.NET Blazor PWA Project run failed in docker

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Created a blazorserver project

```
dotnet new blazorserver -o blazorservertest
```

Created a dockerfile and then it ran in the docker container successfully.

Then I created a blazorwasm project

```
dotnet new blazorwasm -o  --pwa
```

But it ran failed in docker container

```
Could not execute because the application was not found or a compatible .NET SDK is not installed.

Possible reasons for this include:

  * You intended to execute a .NET program:

      The application 'MyBlazorPwaTest1.dll' does not exist.

  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:

      It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.

      Install a .NET SDK from:

        https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

here is my dockerfile of the blazorwasm project

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyBlazorPwaTest1.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "MyBlazorPwaTest1.csproj"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "MyBlazorPwaTest1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyBlazorPwaTest1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyBlazorPwaTest1.dll"]
```

Comment: Check in your .csproj files that your target framework is `net6.0`.

Comment: If you're targeting Linux containers, check that the casing of the DLL file name produced by your project is exactly as specified in your ENTRYPOINT instruction: `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyBlazorPwaTest1.dll"]`. Linux has a case-sensitive file system so if it doesn't match exactly, you'll get this error.